# invoking web services from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, java-me, service

I have to invoke already built web services from my code and get the response in return.
How can I do it?

I am working on Eclipse for BlackBerry phone simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go for ksoap2 for web service call from blackberry.
check [this](http://www.blackberryforums.com/developer-forum/140930-blackberry-jde-ksoap-noobs.html) out